# How can I show sub-categories only when the parent category is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I want to achieve that whenever a user click on any parent category it should show sub-categories of that one below automatically.

I have added `ul.children { display: none; }` as well in stylesheet. So, now it's showing only parent categories.

```js
jQuery('li.cat-item').on('click', function() {
  $('ul.children').hide();
  $(this).find('ul.children').show();
});
```

```css
ul.children {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-25">
  <a href="link">Parent Category</a>

  <ul class="children">
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-13">
      <a href="link">Sub Category</a></li>
  </li>
  </ul>

</li>
```

But this one is not working.

Comment: Two things.  First off, your html snippet has an extra `</li>` that is not matched.  Secondly, you're links are going to a url, so they will perform a page transfer.  That's going to blow away your DOM and make it whatever the link location you go to is.

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery('li.cat-item').on('click',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('ul.children').hide();
    $(this).find('ul.children').show();
});
```

```css
ul.children{ display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-25">
        <a href="link">Parent Category</a>
        <ul class="children">
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-13">
                <a href="link">Sub Category</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li> 
</ul>
```

You haven't nested the menu and submenu items properly. I added `preventDefault` to your jQuery snippet because, according to the [Mozilla Developer Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault):

> The Event interface's preventDefault() method tells the user agent that if the event does not get explicitly handled, its default action should not be taken as it normally would be. The event continues to propagate as usual, unless one of its event listeners calls stopPropagation() or stopImmediatePropagation(), either of which terminates propagation at once.

Comment: @wwe_fan9417 did you copy all snippets? Could you show me your HTML document?